# Не видит данные из функций

Tags: php

Есть некая страница 'worker.php' на которую поступают данные методом пост, которые принимаются таким:

```
if (isset($_POST['something'])) {
  $something = trim(htmlspecialchars(strval($_POST['something'])), " \t\n\0");
```

кодом.
Так как такие данные поступают неоднократно и не только в этом документе в соседнем файле 'functions.php' была создана такая:

```
function text_cleaner($some_text) {
  $some_text = trim(htmlspecialchars(strval($some_text)), " \t\n\0");
}
```

функция, а сам файл был подключён к предыдущему методом:

```
include("functions.php");
```

а в самом файле 'worker.php' было записано:

```
if (isset($_POST['something'])) {
  $something = text_cleaner($_POST['something']), " \t\n\0");
```

после чего данные из POST'а он начал терять.
Подскажите пожалуйста в чём проблема и собственно где я ошибся?

Comment: Возвращать данные из функции кто будет? Пушкин?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы ничего не возвращаете в своей функции `text_cleaner()`, поэтому в переменную `$something` ничего и не записывается. Для этого добавьте оператор `return` перед значением, которое нужно вернуть и использовать в дальнейшем:

```php
function text_cleaner($some_text)
{
    return trim($string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В этой строке

```
$something = text_cleaner($_POST['something']), " \t\n\0");
```

вы не удалили лишнее `, " \t\n\0")`
И функция `text_cleaner` должна возвращать результат:

```
function text_cleaner($some_text){
    return trim(htmlspecialchars(strval($some_text)), " \t\n\0");
}
```